# How to fix my layout for a JFrame program

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix my code so that all of it appears in one column, instead of the two that it keeps giving me, I want it to only be showing one column and have a nice and compact GUI but every time I compile and run, the button sticks out from the rest of the text boxes and labels! Any extra help is also greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Code:

```
package time;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class Display extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Basic out = new Basic();

    public static int hrsIn;
    public static int daysIn;
    public static int monthsIn;
    public static int yearsIn;
    public static int timeAdd;
    public static JButton enter;
    public static JLabel currentTime, nextTime, hoursUntil;
    public static JTextField dayCurrent, hourCurrent, monthCurrent, yearCurrent,
                                dayNext, hourNext, monthNext, yearNext;
    public static JFrame frame;
    public static JPanel newTimePanel;

    public Display(){
        super(new GridLayout(3,1));

        enter = new JButton("Okay");
        dayCurrent = new JTextField("Day", 2);
        hourCurrent = new JTextField("Hour", 2);
        monthCurrent = new JTextField("Month", 2);
        yearCurrent = new JTextField("Year", 4); 
        dayNext = new JTextField("Day", 2);
        hourNext = new JTextField("Hour", 2);
        monthNext = new JTextField("Month", 2);
        yearNext = new JTextField("Year", 4); 
        currentTime = new JLabel("Current Time:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        nextTime = new JLabel("Next Time:", JLabel.RIGHT);
        hoursUntil = new JLabel("xxxx", JLabel.RIGHT);

        JPanel button = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
            button.add(enter);

        JPanel currentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
            currentPane.add(dayCurrent);
            currentPane.add(monthCurrent);
            currentPane.add(yearCurrent);
            currentPane.add(hourCurrent);

        JPanel nextPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
            nextPane.add(dayNext);
            nextPane.add(monthNext);
            nextPane.add(yearNext);
            nextPane.add(hourNext);

        JPanel newTimePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            newTimePanel.add(hoursUntil);

        JPanel labelsCurrent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
            labelsCurrent.add(currentTime);
            labelsCurrent.add(currentPane);

        JPanel labelsNext = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
            labelsNext.add(nextTime);
            labelsNext.add(nextPane);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
            add(labelsCurrent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(labelsNext, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        frame = new JFrame("Clock Adder");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.add(new Display());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
                }
            }
        );
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't use `GridLayout`....

Comment: I tried using BorderLayout and it just made a mess of things

Comment: `static` is NOT your friend!  This will not help you and WILL make your life more difficult!  `static` is not a means to provide inter-object communications!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `GridLayout`, it's doing exactly what it was designed to do, instead, try using `GridBagLayout`, for example...

Replace

```
super(new GridLayout(3,1));
```

With...

```
super(new GridBagLayout());
```

Then replace...

```
add(labelsCurrent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(labelsNext, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(button, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
```

with...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(labelsCurrent, gbc);
add(labelsNext, gbc);
add(button, gbc);
```

[image: Layout]

Take a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details...

You might also want to take a look at [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

**Updated**

Use a `GridBagLayout`, there is little reason to try and use compound layouts here...

[image]

```
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        dayCurrent = new JTextField(3);
        hourCurrent = new JTextField(3);
        monthCurrent = new JTextField(3);
        yearCurrent = new JTextField(3);
        dayNext = new JTextField(3);
        hourNext = new JTextField(3);
        monthNext = new JTextField(3);
        yearNext = new JTextField(3);
        enter = new JButton("Ok");

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);

        add(new JLabel("Day"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(new JLabel("Month"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(new JLabel("Year"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(new JLabel("Hour"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;

        add(new JLabel("Current Time:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(dayCurrent, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(monthCurrent, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(yearCurrent, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(hourCurrent, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;

        add(new JLabel("Next Time:"), gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(dayNext, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(monthNext, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(yearNext, gbc);
        gbc.gridx++;
        add(hourNext, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(enter, gbc);
```

Comment: Sort of worked, still trying to figure out how to make the labels smaller and not just left aligning them, so that the window doesn't have an inch and a half of space on one side

Comment: That is the same window I am getting, but do you have any idea how to make the LABELS smaller, unrelated to the layout, I'm assuming thats why there's that huge space to the left

Comment: It has to do with the fact that the labels and the fields panels are been given half of the available space each for the container they are in, which is EXACTLY how `GridLayout` works...

Comment: This makes sense now! Thanks for all the help and all of the understandable code, really helpful.